# How do I create a scroll view where it stops at a certian view?

Tags: react-native

I have a scroll view and inside the scroll view has multiple views where it displays information that fills up the whole screen. How do I make a scroll view that every time the user swipes down or up, it stops at every view instead of infinitely scrolling? (Kind of like instagram explore scroll where if user swipes down it stops every post)

Comment: try using <Scrollview pagingEnabled />